# how do i use IF ELSE and concatinate string

Tags: excel-formula

Hi i have excel data like this

[image: excel]

so i would like to have a formula field which will combine all string where it has a 'X' marked.

from example above is: "Science;Bio;Math"

Comment: Please review the thoughtful answers given below.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering this formula into cell `F2`:

```
=REPLACE(CONCATENATE(IF(A2 = "x", CONCATENATE(";", A1), ""),
                     IF(B2 = "x", CONCATENATE(";", B1), ""),
                     IF(C2 = "x", CONCATENATE(";", C1), ""),
                     IF(D2 = "x", CONCATENATE(";", D1), "")), 1, 1, "")
```

Here is the formula on a single line:

```
=REPLACE(CONCATENATE(IF(A2 = "x", CONCATENATE(";", A1), ""), IF(B2 = "x", CONCATENATE(";", B1), ""), IF(C2 = "x", CONCATENATE(";", C1), ""), IF(D2 = "x", CONCATENATE(";", D1), "")), 1, 1, "")
```

**Output**

```
Science;Bio;Math
```

Comment: this formula will result in a leading `;` sign if A2 does not have an `x`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing the Concatenate() function does is make you type more. You can do without it.

But you need to make sure there is no leading `;` character if the first cell(s) don't have an X. That can be done by always starting with a `;` character and then using the Replace() function to replace the starting `;` character.

```
=REPLACE(IF(A2="x",";"&A1,"")&IF(B2="x",";"&B1,"")&IF(C2="x",";"&C1,"")&IF(D2="x",";"&D1,""),1,1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: what error? See the screenshot with the formula in action. Do you use the comma or the semicolon as the list separator? You need to accommodate for that. With the comma as the list separator the formula works. Check your setup if it does not.

Comment: I just copied the formula again from the post and pasted into Excel. It works.